# How to remove the internet interfaces?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet, interface

In my internet list there are several wifi id's which is always displaying even I delete them through the GUI.
How am I supposed to get to the interface files and edit the interfaces of ethernet and Wifi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `network-manager`, the location of the connections is:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

You will find all the Wired and Wireless connections here, you can modify or delete any connection if you want.

After making any change run `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Comment: Which means all the  wireless network connections are listed as directories and we need to delete those specific connection. your answer is useful

Comment: @algosig: Yes..

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces`

To get more info, you can visit [Network Configuration](https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/install/configure_networking.html)

To list all your available interfaces, you can use the command `sudo ifconfig -a`

Comment: there is only one interface lo in the /etc/network/interfaces file, not even a single wifi interace to which I am recently connected